# Decoupling Project reference and Dependency Injection

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection

So i have this challenge as below.

I have gradle project structure.

- Main Project

  -- a. Android(#Sub-Project 1)
  -- b. Commons(#Sub-Project 2)
  -- c. Http-Comms(#Sub-Project 3)

**Summary**
I have a 3 projects as above. `HTTP-Comms` has to be independent, it has dependency on the `Commons` project. HTTP-Comms has a interface and implementor which exposes the methods to start and stop the server. Problem is i have a reference of `HTTP-Comms` project in `Android` and want to decouple this. So that a normal build can run **without** this feature and a developer build will run **with** this feature.  If i will not include this project in distribution for a normal build, Android will fail because of ClassNotFound ..

**Briefly explained**
Now this `HTTP-Comms  project` has a NanoHttpdServer implementation and has many classes which reference libraries related to server and other utility classes. Its independent on its own. We have a interface IHttpComms which has methods to start and stop the server

```
interface IHttpComms{
  public void startServer();
  public void stopServer();
  public void serveRequest();
}

class Controller implements IhttpComms{

 //Implements the feature
 // reference to other classes in the HTTP-Comms project.

}
```

Now There is another `Android project` which has action button to Start and Stop the server. So it depends on `HTTP-Comms` project. Here i am doing

```
IhttpComms comms = new Controller();
```

hence making a tight coupling between the HTTP-Comms and Android project.

Where as `Commons project` can be referred and should have the common code between these projects. `But Commons project cannot hold reference to HTTP-COMMS`

Now as HTTP-Comms is a incubating feature for us, we require it not to be part of the build process at some times.

My Question is ...

1. Can i use any dependency injection framewroks, and i will stil be able to ***inject the dependent object outside the project.*** ?? Like have a instance of Controller and inject to Android ?
2. Without DI frameworks.. any other design pattern solution ?

Comment: Is this Android project is driver project? I mean is it running by itself or main project is driver project and it uses android one ?

Comment: @Erkan Main project has grade scripts to run task in order required..  And common project is used in both android and http-comms project

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that both IhttpComms and its implementation are in the same project/jar.  I would move IhttpComms into its own project and have Android project reference this new project, which should only have Interfaces and Abstract classes only.  This way you decouple your Android project from concrete classes in Http-Comms. Then you are free to use whatever implementation of IhttpComms you like and you load it at runtime using (you guessed it) a DI framework or even the humble Class.forName

To summarize:

1. IHttp-Comms: new project only interfaces, no dependencies
2. Android(#Sub-Project 1)  dependency to IHttp-Comms
3. Commons(#Sub-Project 2)
4. Http-Comms(#Sub-Project 3) , IHttp-Comms implementation (concrete classes) with dependency to IHttp-Comms and Commons